# Suggestive Actions within Waterfall Dialog not getting triggered?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

### Screenshots

[image]

Dialog 
[image]

### Version

4.6.0
Using directline to use in website

### Describe the bug

I am trying to trigger a waterfall dialog during the intro of the bot session. I want to show a few suggestive card options along with an intro and use waterfall to follow those steps. But unfortunately, the suggestive actions are not getting triggered? Is it because maybe I need to pass the context to the dialog and trigger the suggestive actions from that context instead of the dialog context?

if I send a normal text message from the dialog it works fine but not the suggestive action
`return await step.context.sendActivity('Welcome' );`

### Expected behavior

When I load the bot in the web I expect to see the bot greets me some suggestive card options. It has to trigger the WELCOME dialog and display the suggestive actions

### Where the suggestive Action is working

For example: if I trigger the suggestive action inside async onTurn directly without calling the dialog then it works fine. But if I do it this way I will not be able to followup the clicks on the suggestive actions to steps so i wanted to call the dialog and do the activity within the waterfall dialog

```
  async onTurn(context) {
if (context.activity.name === 'webchat/join') {
var suggestlist = [{
                    type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
                    title: ji18n('option 1'),
                    value: { id: '1000000', type: 'option1' }
                }];



                var suggestedAction = MessageFactory.suggestedActions(suggestlist);

                return await step.context.sendActivity(suggestedAction);

}  
})
```

Comment: Have you tried sending the same suggestive actions in other dialogs and that works fine? If so try sending them in this dialog without  await step.context.sendActivity(suggestedAction) and then return await step.endDialog();

Comment: @MarcAsmar Yes it works in other places but not when I am trying to show the suggestive action within a dialog. 

I have updated the question with some scenario where its working.

Answer (score 0):

The title property of your `suggestList` requires a `string` value, however `ji18n()` returns an object. I believe this is what is blocking your `suggestedAction` from rendering.

Consider implementing the following, as referenced in the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ji18n):

```js
.addDialog( new WaterfallDialog(MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
  async ( step ) => {
    const activity = step.context.activity;

    const input = {
      "option1": [{
        "$": {
          "en-US": `This is "option 1" in English`,
          "fr-FR": `Il s'agit de "l'option 1" en anglais`
        }
      }]
    }

    const output = ji18n(input, activity.locale)
    console.log('Output ', output['option1'][0])

    const suggestList = [{
      type: ActionTypes.PostBack,
      title: output['option1'][0],
      value: { id: '1000000', type: 'option1' }
    }]

    const suggestedAction = MessageFactory.suggestedActions( suggestList )
    return await step.context.sendActivity( suggestedAction );
  }
]))
```

**English result returned as output & button title:**

[image]

[image]

**French result returned as output & button title:**

[image]

[image]

Hope of help!

Comment: Thanks for your response but still this does not work. I hope someone from the community can help me out.

Comment: This issue is been for 2 months also addressed the same with Microsoft and still waiting for update. Mean while any support from the community could be helpful.

using the latest version of node , npm botbuilder, 

Even the suggestive options are not getting triggered within step 2 of the waterfall.